# Longest pathname string in Mac OS X HFS+

Tags: macos, path, max

I'm trying to find a definitive answer (e.g. Apple developer documentation) for the maximum length of a complete path string on Mac OS X. I've seen various non-authoritative sites that state that it is unbounded, 4096 characters, or 1024 characters, but haven't been able to find an answer on Apple's web site.

Comment: I'm not sure it does - when we grappled with the question it's always been in a programming context.

Comment: Doug is correct; I am posing this problem in the context of a development project which needs to install/read/write files in a cross-platform manner.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you look in `/usr/include/sys/syslimits.h` on a Leopard system, you'll see:

```
#define PATH_MAX                 1024   /* max bytes in pathname */
```

Furthermore, [Technical Note 1150: HFS Plus Volume Format](http://developer.apple.com/technotes/tn/tn1150.html), in discussing symbolic links, says:

> "For maximum compatibility, the length of the path should be 1024 bytes or less."

Answer (score 2):

You might find this useful: 
http://rentzsch.com/macosx/pathmaxBlackholing

1024 bytes is correct.